# Access Deep Freeze without tray icon and key combination

Tags: windows, deep-freeze

Is there a way to access the Deep Freeze control panel without using the tray icon (not shown) and without using the Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F6 key combination?

Answer (score 0):

If it's an enterprise version of Deep Freeze, you can use their console or dfc.exe to do it remotely.

Answer (score -1):

## No.

Those are the only provided ways to access the Deep Freeze control panel.